# Grab numbers from web page datatables

Tags: python, web-scraping

I very often need to setup physical properties for some technical computations. It is not convenient to fill in such data by hand. I would like to **grab such data from some public webpage (Wikipedia for example) using python script.**

I was trying several ways:

- using html parser like **lxml.etree** (I have no experience - I was just trying to follow tutorial)
- using **pandas wikitable import** ( --,,-- )
- using **urllib2** do download html source and than search for keywords by **regular expressions**

**What I'm able to do:**

I didn't find any universal solution applicable for various sources of information. The only script I made which actually works does use just simple urllib2 and regular expression. It can grab physical properties of elements from [this page](http://environmentalchemistry.com/yogi/periodic/C.html) which is plain HTML.

**What I'm not able to do:**

I'm not able to do that with more sophisticated web pages  [like this](http://www.substech.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=thermoplastic_acrylonitrile-butadiene-styrene_abs). The HTML code of this page which I grab by urllib2 does not contain the keywords and data I'm looking for ( like Flexural strength, Modulus of elasticity )? **Actually it seem that it does not contain the wikipage at all!** How is that possible? Are these wiki-tables linked somehow dynamically? How can I get contend of the table by urllib? Why urllib2 does not grab this data, and my web browser does?

I have no experience with web programming.
I don't understand why it is so hard to get any machine-readable data from free public online sources of information.

Comment: I usually do such the quick and dirty way: copy table from browser, paste it into Notepad++, use regexes to beat the cr... useful data out of it, and change the separators whatever they might be with \t, and then copy and paste it into a spreadsheet. Of course, if you have to do this regularly, or for more than say 5 tables, this is not an option...

Answer (score 1):

Web scraping is difficult. Not because it's rocket science, but because it's just messy. For the moment you'll need to hand-craft scrapers for different sites and use them as long as the site's structure does not change.

There are more automated approaches to web information extraction, e.g. like it is described in this paper: [Harvesting Relational Tables from Lists on the Web](http://www.research.att.com/techdocs/TD_100467.pdf), but this is not mainstream yet.

> A large number of web pages contain data structured in the form of “lists”.
>   Many such lists can be further split into multi-column **tables**, which can then be used
>   in more semantically meaningful tasks. However, harvesting relational tables from such
>   lists can be a challenging task. The lists are manually generated and hence need not
>   have well deﬁned templates – they have inconsistent delimiters (if any) and often have
>   missing information.

---

However, there are a lot of tools to get to the (HTML) content more quickly, e.g. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library designed for quick turnaround projects like screen-scraping.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup
>>> import urllib
>>> page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.substech.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?"
               "id=thermoplastic_acrylonitrile-butadiene-styrene_abs").read()
>>> soup = Soup(page) # the HTML gets parsed here
>>> soup.findAll('table')
```

Example output: https://friendpaste.com/DnWDviSiHIYQEBduTqkWd. More documentation can be found here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree.

If you want to extract data from a bigger set of pages, take a look at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by

> it seem that it does not contain the wikipage at all

I got this relatively rapidly:

```
import httplib
import re

hostu = 'www.substech.com'
timeout = 7
hypr = httplib.HTTPConnection(host=hostu,timeout = timeout)

rekete_page = ('/dokuwiki/doku.php?id='
               'thermoplastic_acrylonitrile-butadiene-styrene_abs')

hypr.request('GET',rekete_page)
x = hypr.getresponse().read()
hypr.close()

#print '\n'.join('%d %r' % (i,line) for i,line in enumerate(x.splitlines(1)))

r = re.compile('\t<tr>\n.+?\t</tr>\n',re.DOTALL)

r2 = re.compile('<th[^>]*>(.*?)</th>')
r3 = re.compile('<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>')

for y in r.findall(x):
    print
    #print repr(y)
    print map(str.strip,r2.findall(y))
    print map(str.strip,r3.findall(y))
```

result

```
[]
['<strong>Thermoplastic</strong>']

[]
['<strong>Acrylonitrile</strong><strong>-Butadiene-Styrene (ABS)</strong>']

[]
['<strong>Property</strong>', '<strong>Value in metric unit</strong>', '<strong>Value in </strong><strong>US</strong><strong> unit</strong>']

['Density']
['1.05 *10\xc2\xb3', 'kg/m\xc2\xb3', '65.5', 'lb/ft\xc2\xb3']

['Modulus of elasticity']
['2.45', 'GPa', '350', 'ksi']

['Tensile strength']
['45', 'MPa', '6500', 'psi']

['Elongation']
['33', '%', '33', '%']

['Flexural strength']
['70', 'MPa', '10000', 'psi']

['Thermal expansion (20 \xc2\xbaC)']
['90*10<sup>-6</sup>', '\xc2\xbaC\xcb\x89\xc2\xb9', '50*10<sup>-6</sup>', 'in/(in* \xc2\xbaF)']

['Thermal conductivity']
['0.25', 'W/(m*K)', '1.73', 'BTU*in/(hr*ft\xc2\xb2*\xc2\xbaF)']

['Glass transition temperature']
['100', '\xc2\xbaC', '212', '\xc2\xbaF']

['Maximum work temperature']
['70', '\xc2\xbaC', '158', '\xc2\xbaF']

['Electric resistivity']
['10<sup>8</sup>', 'Ohm*m', '10<sup>10</sup>', 'Ohm*cm']

['Dielectric constant']
['2.4', '-', '2.4', '-']
```